# Exporting Data from Netlogo

Tags: export

I am aware that netlogo is capable of exporting data, but from my understanding I can only get it to export data from a particular snapshot in time. I would like to see how the data changes over time for all of the ticks in the run. Is there a way to get netlogo to do this? Or perhaps tell it to export data for particular intervals  (e.g. every 10 ticks starting from time 0)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the BehaviorSpace tool. Set up an experiment with the input parameters you need (or ranges for some of them) and the names of the variables that you want exported (or code that creates what you want) and run the experiment with reporting every tick.

A more complicated way that may be better in some situations is to have a procedure called something like `print-results` and, at the end of the go procedure have the line `if ticks mod 10 = 0 print-results` and in the print-results procedure, have a bunch of print, show etc statements for the results you want reported. then do an `export-output`